# Prepare the body of an Http post request from an object

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, httprequest

To send the body of an http post request in angular I use the following implementation:

```
  let requestBody: String = "";

  //dataObjectis the object that contains the values to send from the form
  for (let key in dataObject) {
    if (dataObject[key]) {
      requestBody += (body.length ? '&' : '') + key + "=" + dataObject[key];
    }
  }
```

Then I use the `requestBody` in my http post request like this:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
//http is an Http instance
http.post(URI, requestBody, requestOptions)
```

I am wondering if there is any better way or a 'ready to use' method that allows to use directly the object `dataObject` in the post method instead of using the above implementation.

Comment: You could try with JSON.stringify() ;)

Comment: I think that JSON.stringify() won't work with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type (I just edited my question to add the Content-Type)

Comment: You can "post" many different kinds of data. Have you considered posting 'application/json' Content-Type instead? If your dataObject is in a JavaScript Object type already, no need to convert it to form data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a method with the deprecated Http Module. The new HttpClient support this.

```
constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let params = new HttpParams()
    params = params.set('a', '1')
    http.post('/api/v1/login', params, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {});

}
```

Comment: the second parameter of the `post` method should be the body of the request. If there is any parameter of the request, shouldn't it be sent within the third parameter of the `post` method?

Comment: If you want to send the params as Post Form data they belong in the body part of the method, because they are the body of teh request. If you want to send them as Url Params you have to put them into the object of the third parameter with the key params `{headers: headers, params: params}`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `URLSearchParams`:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

//...

let requestBody = new URLSearchParams();

for (let key in dataObject) {
  requestBody.set(key, dataObject[key]);
}
```